# Getting 'System.OutOfMemoryException' during foreach loop

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-4.0

I am retrieving bulk data from database and making changes in that data but it give me error outofmemoryexception. below is my code

```
public void AddArticleRefrences(ref List<Article> art)
{
    string blueWordStyle = "text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #663366;color: #0000CC;";
    ArticalDAO objArt = new ArticalDAO();
    List<Article> MainArticle = objArt.GetListArticle(1);

    foreach (Article main in MainArticle)
    {
        foreach (var content in art)
        {
            content.Contents = Regex.Replace(content.Contents, main.Header, string.Format("<a href='{0}' target='_blank' style='{1}'>{2}</a>", "ViewArticle.aspx?Code=" + main.ArticleCode, blueWordStyle, main.Header));
        }
    }
}
```

It gives me error in `content.Contents`

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using `ref` for the parameter? I suspect it doesn't mean what you think it means...

Comment: i used ref to argument to be passed by reference to that method which can do changes in data.

Comment: But you're not changing `art` - you're changing the *contents* of the list, potentially, but you're not changing the object it refers to. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: I don't know yet - partly as we don't know anything about `main.Header` or `content.Contents`...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Regex object and after your operation you have to assign null to them so they will available for GC, Replace you inner foreach code with following.

```
    Regex objRegex = new Regex(main.Header); 
    content.Contents =  objRegex.Replace(content.Contents, string.Format("<a href='{0}' target='_blank' style='{1}'>{2}</a>", "ViewArticle.aspx?Code=" + main.ArticleCode, blueWordStyle, main.Header));
    objRegex = null;
```